# partial refreshing for viewmodel collection in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

not too sure.. but this is really tricky for me..

I have an mvc page with Customer as the viewmodel as resource bind to the page. In the Customer viewmodel, it has `IList<Contact>` (a collection of contacts). In the page the user can update his detail and his contact detail and also adding more contact details.

while adding a new contact detail, how can i do a partial load so the page refreshes the collection of contact details only without refreshing the entire page? also how can i re-bind the `IList<Contact>` to the customer view model so when the user clicks on the save button all the data are shipped as one customer viewmodel to the controller?

here is the defenition of customer viewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IList<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

}
```

Page definition:

```
    @model Models.CustomerViewModel

    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MemberLayout.cshtml";
    }

    foreach(var contact on Model.Contacts)
    {
        //population happens here
    }

   <a href="#" id="AddNewContact">Add New Contact</a> //this will pops up a new dialog to add new contact
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) useful. It shows a nice technique that could be used to dynamically add/remove elements from a collection.

Comment: seen this post before posting the thread.. the post only cover the collection list..